# Unable to consistently load large json response using jquery.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, post

Recently I started facing issue with one of my scripts that loads a json response from the server. I am using jquery.ajax() to make an ajax call. The code snippet is so -

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: "script.jsp",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(response) {
     console.log(response);
  }, 
  error: function(response, error) {
     console.log(response, error);
  }
});
```

As I mentioned this script worked as recent as yesterday. I have not made any changes to either the server-side code or the front-end code. The json response is a bit large ~1 MB in size. But I validated the json output using -

```
python -mjson.tool < output.json
```

It prints out properly. Curious thing is FF & Chrome handle it differently.

In FF, I open firebug and see the ajax request being made. I see that the request is served in around 300ms but the loading wheel next to the link in the console is still animating for aorund 20 seconds. And after that the json response is properly processed and the result can be seen on the page. In IE also similar behavior, proper processing of the json after 20 seconds.

In Chrome, nothing happens for around 20 seconds after which I see an error in the console saying either `"error": undefined` or `Failed to load resource`. Alternatively it also prints the below stacktrace -

```
POST script.jsp 
f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.sendjquery.min.js:4
f.extend.ajaxjquery.min.js:4
DataTableWidget.extend._fetchBuildingBlockItemsPermissionBBItemsWidget.js:91
(anonymous function)PermissionBBItemsWidget.js:83
e.extend.eachjquery.min.js:2
DataTableWidget.extend._loadDataPermissionBBItemsWidget.js:82
DataTableWidget.extend.showPermissionBBItemsWidget.js:15
(anonymous function)permission-building-blocks.html:451
xLAB.min.js:5
ULAB.min.js:5
jLAB.min.js:5
ILAB.min.js:5
eLAB.min.js:5
a.onload.a.onreadystatechange
```

I dont understand this weird behavior in different browsers.

So in essence I made sure that -

1. Server side code returns the response fast. I put in some debug statements and saw the server log. None of the response form server take more than 500ms.
2. Made sure than json is properly validated. The fact that after 20 secs it is processed in both IE & FF without any issues is a proof of that. In addition to use of python's json.tool.
3. Set the dataType to json

So any pointers on the issue will be a great help. Thanks.

**UPDATE**
One more curious thing I noticed. While the request is being processed and I hit the refresh button even within 3 seconds of the original request, the process immediately completes. As in I see changes in the view of course fraction of a second later the page is wiped out due to refresh event.

**UPDATE 2**
I have noticed that after I slice up my big response by alphabets. The issue of looong response happens in only certain responses. I ran this split long response files through  http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/#jsonformatter and although it immediately returns saying that the josn is valid, it takes 20+ seconds to actually pretty print the response. I think the problem is happening due to certain characters like `\u0026` so with this added info, how to resolve the problem? [Here is the snipet of the problematic json.](https://gist.github.com/0e60391f9589ab6ed619)

Comment: time to consider supplying some of that data based on demand perhaps??

Comment: @charlietfl I did think about that but I fail to understand why would it work yesterday and not today. Also in one other page I make comparable request with no issues at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem. The issue was with how the server-side code provided the client-side code JavaScript with the json string.

I was using a legacy method in our code base which actually rendered the already json string in a jsp page before passing it to the client. This was somehow screwing up the response. Also response type was text/html because of this.

As soon as I switched the response to be of actual application/json MIME type stream, everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

does your JSON have line feeds?  Do you have Firebug or something line that open?  The browser may be loading the JSON just fine, it might be your debugging tools crapping out.  I Recall having issues before with inspecting certain JSON strings with certain tools just because it didn't have line feeds  (or line feeds as understood in Windows).  I'm wondering if the fact your logging the whole thing to the console doesn't have something to do with it.

Comment: I'll give another example.  I'm not sure what your operating system of choice is, for the sake of experiment, I'll assume Windows.  Try opening a long, line-feed less (maybe your JSON file) in windows Notepad.  It may take a good 15/20 seconds to load.  Now if you try opening it in something like GVim, which is the modern open source conception of an editor that's been around for maybe 40 years, it should open instantaneously.  IIRC, though, with certain settings, it too, will act just like Notepad.  Most editors are not designed to handle long, line-feed-less files.

Comment: And the only reason I'm talking about editors is that most debugging environments deal with the same issue similarly (and poorly), if that makes what I'm trying to explain any clearer.

Comment: Thanks. But I figured out he problem. The issue was with hom the backend provided the front-end code with the json string. I used a legacy method which actually printed out the already json string in a jsp page and then supply that to the front-end. As soon as I switched the response to be of actual application/json MIME type stream, everything was fine.